# SP page into template

Tags: wiki-pages, template

I've added a page to my recently created site (also created my own master page)... everything is fine.  It's a two column layout and the left hand column has been modified to be a bit smaller then the default.   There is a table of data in both the right and left side.

I'd like to take this page, and make it into some sort of template now.  It's basically a format I want people to utilizing when adding new wiki items to the site so its consistent for others when viewing.   What's the easiest way?  At the end of the day, I want a user (not that technical) to be able to do something like "add a new page" and it will open up this template and allow them to edit the template.  They will fill in their subject, links (on both sides of the layout) and add any additional material.

The users will not have access to sharepoint designer software, just the web interface.  I am using Sharepoint 2013.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good Explanation of (i hope) what you want to do:

http://richardstk.com/2013/08/02/tweaking-the-blank-web-part-page-template-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I'm waiting on IT to give me access as I don't see "page layouts" in SP designer.  Is that access related or can I enable it somewhere?

Also, to define what I'm trying to do:
http://postimg.org/image/5r2du1h0v/

Comment: sorry for multiple comments, won't let me edit..

from that link, when someone adds a page, I'd like them to start with that if possible.  They need to be able to edit though.  Perhaps not as much content as you see on the left hand side... 

second to that, if that is the case - would there be any way to also let someone add a blank page in the future (like two options when adding a new page)?

Comment: You can edit the page also in the notepad. Go to Site Settings > Look and Feel > Design Manager for creating new layouts or to Page layouts and site templates to edit already existing. A post on this: http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.de/2013/08/create-custom-page-layouts-in.html

Comment: if I don't see "Design Manager" under my Look and Feel Options - is that soley access related?

IT guy is helping but doesn't seem the most knowledgeable on the topic either.   Just trying to get as much info as possible.

Comment: Yes, if you can't see this options, than you have not enough permission. You need at least ''Designer'' permission.

Comment: it seems like I have Full Control, Design, Edit & contribute access.  Would that not suffice or is something else specifically that I am missing?